# How to show the age of time in flutter from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I try to show age of time the time I was save in MySQL with post. With each new publication that will be added to the database, the time of the addition will be placed with it.

Pictures that show what I'm trying to do:
[image]

MySQL:

[image]

PHP file:

```
<?php

include 'cn.php';
    
$sql="SELECT *  FROM `Time`";
 
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 


$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();


$array = array();

while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{


    $array[] = $row;
}


echo ($result) ?
json_encode(array("code" => 1, "result"=>$array)) :
json_encode(array("code" => 0, "message"=>"Data not found !"));


?>
```

Flutter Page code:

```
class _TimeAgeState extends State<TimeAge> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    GatData();
  }

  bool _isLoading = false;
  List data = [];
   var TimeNowAge;
  Future<String?> GatData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("***************************"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
    data = convertDataToJson['result'];

    setState(() {

      TimeNowAge = data[0]['timetest'];

      _isLoading = false;
      log("timetest :${TimeNowAge.toString()}");
    });
  }






  _convertDate(timestamp) {
    String difference = "";
    final date = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
    final currentDate = DateTime.now();
    final differenceInMinutes = currentDate.difference(date).inMinutes;

    if (differenceInMinutes == 0) {
      difference = "a moment ago";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 60) {
      difference = "a minute before $differenceInMinutes";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 1440) {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 60} hours ago";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 10080) {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 1440} days ago";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 43800) {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 10080} a week ago";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 525600) {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 43800} a month ago";
    } else {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 525600} years ago";
    }
    return difference;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [



          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
          _isLoading
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : Center(child: Text(_convertDate(TimeNowAge)))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get this problem:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
```

[image]

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work directly with DateTime of TimeNow

```
_convertDate(timestamp) {
    String difference = "";
    //final date = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp );
    final currentDate = DateTime.now();
    final differenceInMinutes = currentDate.difference(DateTime(timestamp.year, timestamp.month, timestamp.day)).inMinutes;

    if (differenceInMinutes == 0) {
      difference = "a moment ago";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 60) {
      difference = "a minute before $differenceInMinutes";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 1440) {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 60} hours ago";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 10080) {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 1440} days ago";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 43800) {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 10080} a week ago";
    } else if (differenceInMinutes < 525600) {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 43800} a month ago";
    } else {
      difference = "${differenceInMinutes ~/ 525600} years ago";
    }
    return difference;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print(date);
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      child: Center(
          child: Text(_convertDate(TimeNow))
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi bro / I get this problem with your code (Class 'String' has no instance getter 'year'.
Receiver: "09:20:39"
Tried calling: year)

Comment: You're trying with time, need to work with Datetime(timetest).